# How to manage multiple tables with the same structure (redux)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I found this question, which is similar to a problem that I would like to solve:

[How to manage multiple tables with the same structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179789/how-to-manage-multiple-tables-with-the-same-structure)

However, due to the craptastical nature of VB, the solution doesn't really work. It specifically doesn't work because VB.NET requires the implementation of each method/property in the interface to be explicitly declared.

As for the problem that I'm really trying to solve, here it is:

- I have many lookup/domain tables in the database that all have the same structure
- The items in these tables are typically used for drop downs in the interface
- I would like to avoid a bunch of boilerplate repository methods to retrieve the contents of these tables (one method per table really sucks when you have 40 tables)
- I am **not** using the One True Lookup Table anti-pattern and this is not an option

Does anyone have another solution for this that work work in VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that we ended up using:

```
Public Function GetDomainTableList(tableName As String) As IEnumerable(Of Object)

    Dim table = CType(GetType(FECEntities).GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(DB, Nothing), IEnumerable(Of Object))

    Dim dt = From r In table
             Select r

    Return dt.ToList()

End Function
```

I had originally thought that this wouldn't work for us since I was trying to project each object returned into a `DomainTableItem` class that I had written. But then I realized that the `SelectList` constructor didn't really care about the type of object that it takes in. You just pass in a String containing the property name and it uses reflection to pull out the value.

So everything works out peachy this way and I avoided writing one method per domain/lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Generic Repository should work in this case. There are many available [online](http://geekswithblogs.net/seanfao/archive/2009/12/03/136680.aspx) or you can write a simpler one for just the lookup tables.